# 3 models table relationship ruby on rails semi messy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Updated**

is this ok?

---

```
Student

has_many: hosts
has_many: posts through :students


Post

belongs_to :host
belongs_to :student

Host 

has_many posts
has_many students through posts
```

============

I am working on a platform where students can make an account and post reviews of host families that they lived with.

Currently I have three models

a student model, a host model, and a post model

I want the view to eventually have this displayed information

landlord contact (from host model), 
landlord phone etc (host model),
a review of this particular host in a description box (post) 
and posted by a student

This is a part of my student.rb

```
  has_many :posts
  has_many :hostfamilies
```

This is a part of my post.rb

```
belongs_to :student 

belongs_to :host
```

This is a part of my host.rb

```
belongs_to :student

has_many :posts
```

I have two test pages with some fake data

my index.html.erb under studentscontroller currently looks like this

```
发表者: <%= @student.first_name%> <%=@student.last_name %>
<br>
评论: 
<br>
<% @student.posts.each do |post| %>
  Post <%= post.id %>
  Message: <%= post.message %>
<br>
发表時間: <%= post.created_at %>
<% end %>
```

and my index.html.erb under hostscontroller look like this

```
房東: <%= @host.contact_person %><br>
房東號碼: <%= @host.contact_number %><br>
最近的巴士: <%= @host.nearest_bus %><br>
最近的火車站: <%= @host.nearest_transit %><br>
每月房租: <%= @host.cost %>
```

so far both of them are working correctly.

First I feel like I can use a better table associations relationship than just belongs_to and has_many because these two are relatively easy for me and pretty straight forward. Is there a better way/cleaner way to hook up these 3 tables? I am just a bit confused on how to hook up these three tables. I am building and learning rails at the same time so I have very little experience optimization table associations.

Answer (score 1):

Well if a student has many hosts and a host has many posts you can try out a has_many  :through relationship between. so you would do

student.rb

has_many :posts, through :hosts

check out the rails guides for more info
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

student.rb

```
has_many :hosts
has_many :posts, through: hosts
```

host.rb

```
belongs_to :student
has_many :posts
```

post.rb

```
belongs_to :student
belongs_to :host
```

This way you can get the posts that belong to a specific host,all the posts that a student has posted and all the posts that a student has posted about a host.